# NPM and Life Cycle Operation Order

Tags: npm

I find this liste for "Life Cycle Operation Order":

```
preinstall, install, postinstall, prepublish, preprepare, prepare, postprepare
```

So I use `preinstall` with a commande line. My commande line is a aws cli commande. This command modify the `.npmrc` file (add authentification). When my script execute `install` phase, my new version of my `.npmrc` file is not taken into account.

**I'm obligated to relaunch my commande line** `npm install`

(`<123456789>` and `<me>` is modified for stackoverflow)

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npm run co:login",
    "co:login": "aws codeartifact login --tool npm --repository my-repo --domain my-domain --domain-owner <123456789> --profile <me> --namespace @tp-npm",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "@my-npm/my-common": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's my understanding from reading https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/8806015fdd025f73ccf4001472370eafd3c5a856/lib/npm.js#L63 that the config is loaded once when you invoke `npm` even if there are multiple scripts executed as part of the lifecycle, so you can't modify .npmrc in a preinstall like that.

Comment: @Joe, is it possible run npm install with option in preinstall and add condition on previouse option in preinstall ?

Comment: I don't know.  Haven't tried.